# how do i sum up values and auto display them using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

```
<?php
@$mg = $_POST['mg'];
@$pp = $_POST['pp'];
@$wu = $_POST['wu'];
@$a = $_POST['bc'];
@$b = 200;
@$c = 199;
@$d = 250;
@$e = 198;



if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    @$sum = $a * $b;
    @$summ = $mg * $c;
    @$sump = $pp * $d;
    @$sumu = $wu * $e;
}

?>
```

```html
<form method="POST">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>$</th>
            <th>N</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="name">Bitcoin:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="bc" placeholder="Enter Amount">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="<?php echo @$sum ?>" id="name">
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="name">Western Union:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="wu" id="name" placeholder="Enter Amount">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="<?php echo @$sumu ?>" id="name" placeholder="">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="name">Pay pal:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="pp" id="name" placeholder="Enter Amount">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="<?php echo @$sump ?>" id="name" placeholder="">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="name">Money Gram:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Amount">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="<?php echo @$summ ?>" id="name" placeholder="">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
```

I developed a simple calculator application on my website with two input fields where you like enter a value and it multiplies by 200, and the other input field should be where the result will be outputted. But I am looking for a better way round it much more dynamic like you enter your value and once your mouse leaves the input field it brings out the answer unlike creating a submit button for it. Please any idea on how to go about is did be appreciated.

Comment: You can add javascript to respond to every `keyup` event and write code in that function.

Comment: I got lost by your tags. Where exactly does your difficulty lie? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you need to sum the values on the html or PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/e8e5y3of/

First and foremost, you should understand `id` should contain unique value. That means, if you declared once, you shouldn't repeat it later.

I have corrected your code by assigning separate `id` for each input tag.

HTML CODE :

```
<form method="POST">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>$</th>
                <th>N</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="name">Bitcoin:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="nameb" name="bc" placeholder="Enter Amount">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" id="namebitcoin">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="name">Western Union:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="wu" id="namew" placeholder="Enter Amount">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" id="namewesternunion" placeholder="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="name">Pay pal:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="pp" id="namep" placeholder="Enter Amount">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" id="namepaypal" placeholder="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="name">Money Gram:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="namem" placeholder="Enter Amount">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" id="namemoneygram" placeholder="">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

And for listening event, use `keyup` function.

JS CODE :

```
$( "#nameb" ).keyup(function() {
  var bitcoinvalue = $( "#nameb" ).val() * 200;
    $("#namebitcoin").val(bitcoinvalue);
});

$( "#namew" ).keyup(function() {
  var bitcoinvalue = $( "#namew" ).val() * 200;
    $("#namewesternunion").val(bitcoinvalue);
});

$( "#namep" ).keyup(function() {
  var bitcoinvalue = $( "#namep" ).val() * 200;
    $("#namepaypal").val(bitcoinvalue);
});

$( "#namem" ).keyup(function() {
  var bitcoinvalue = $( "#namem" ).val() * 200;
    $("#namemoneygram").val(bitcoinvalue);
});
```

It listen the input and multiply with 200. You can change it according to your need.

[WORKING FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e8e5y3of/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Raj, thanks a lot everyone will check that up immediately, I deeply appreciate

Comment: @Etimbuk Cool. Accept and upvote if it helps.

Comment: Cant link both files together, please can you show me how to do that @Raj, I am actually novice on javascript. i have tried linking it using [<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calc.js"></script> on the head of the HTML page but its not working, please can you guide me through?  Thanks

Comment: Hey @Raj, i ve figured it out, thanks a million. Had to attach a jquery file too.